# How to reshape a DataFrame with a existed column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to data analysis with python, there is a simple problem here looking for solution. I'm using `pandas` module.

An example subset of which is shown below:

[image]

As you can see, there is a DataFrame with 3 columns and then I split the `record_date` into 3 parts.

[image]

Now the problem is how can I change the DataFrame into such a format like this:

[image]

Comment: Do _not_ post your code or data on other sites. Instead, paste as much as necessary of them into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sample dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        record_date=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=24, freq='2M'),
        user_id=np.arange(8).repeat(3) + 1,
        power_consumption=np.random.randint(100, 500, size=24)
    ))[['record_date', 'user_id', 'power_consumption']]
```

Then you can set the index appropriately and `unstack`

```
rd = df.record_date
d1 = df.set_index([rd.dt.year, rd.dt.month, rd.dt.day, 'user_id'])
d1 = d1.rename_axis(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'user_id']).power_consumption

d1.unstack().T
```

[image]